# Regex for URL with GET variable

Tags: regex, string, mod-rewrite

Trying to get a regex for any string that matches `view.php` with the GET variable `file` with as value `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`. FYI, I need to rewrite this URL to `/file/value`

What I did but didn't work: `^view.php\?.*?(&|\?)file=([a-zA-Z0-9_]*).*$`

What does work?

Comment: Will this regex be ran against a string starting with `view.php` or will it be ran against the entire url?

Comment: No, only the local path, forgot to mention it. So it starts with `view.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading `^` means your entire string begins with view.php, which is probably not true.
Also in your regex your assume, that `file` is the last GET
etc.

This regex should match get value for `file` in any string

```
view\.php\?.*?\bfile=(\w*)\b
```

Comment: Not an optimal solution: http://regex101.com/r/vF5bI8 -- Better solution: http://regex101.com/r/kQ1wP3 (NOTE: I have not really looked at the question, just your solution)

Comment: @Lindrian read the question and if you know and understand regex, you will see why my solution is better. Automatically created regexes containing unused and often wrong stuff.

Comment: I have. Your solution is still bad. The one I provided is better. I don't know where you got "automatically created" from, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Lindrian so tell me please why it's bad and why exactly yours is better?

Comment: Yours will not necessarily match `file=` attribute. It can match anything ending in it. Mind is by no means perfect in this matter, I just added a word boundary to prove a point. You can extend that in any way you like. Further, escaping `&` is unnecessary. Using a capturing group is redundant. Better solution would have been `(?:[& ]|$)`. Not only that, checking for a 'space' is also not optimal. Once again, word boundaries win. A tip: `\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @Lindrian I agree about boundaries but don't see why (?:[& ]|$) is better than (&|$| ). Can you explain?

Comment: You are using several alternations instead of using the proper method which is `[character classes]`. You are also using a capturing group which is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

- `view.php\?` here you accept `viewaphp?`. Is that ok? You probably mean `view\.php`. Also, you enforce a question mark at the end, whereas:
- `(&|\?)` here you again enforce either an ampersand or a question mark. Hence, you require something like `view.php??file=...` or `view.php?.*&file=...`

What you want is probably something like (although untested, and note the + to not allow empty filenames):

`^view\.php\?(?:file=)|(?:.*&file=)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?:&|$)`

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment on Vlad's post, so I do it here: It accepts not only `file=...` but `badfile=...`. What in my regex is insufficient you think?

Comment: I do not understand your regex and it gives me a 500 (I'm using it for mod-rewrite). What is the semicolon : for? And why don't you end with $?

Comment: I'll see if I can compile it to look for errors.. It's not semicolon, just a regular colon. A substring match (x) will be indexed and reached by `\1` or `$1` depending on your language. However, if you don't want to capture the data, you can type (?:x). See here for a more thorough answer: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html . The `(?:&|$)` was silly now that I look at it. Could have been just `&|$` which means "after the filename, either another parameter should be there (&) or it's the end of the string".

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for your work and looking forward to your compiling! Could take a while before I can respond though.

Comment: Perhaps you regex parser doesn't get `?:`... Try this: `^view\.php\?(file=)|(.*&file=)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)&|$` and get the third capture.

Comment: It was not about the `?:` but that it didn't end with `$` I think. However this is working. @Vlad-L 's answer is shorter though, so I accepted his answer. Thanks anyway, I upvoted you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Lindrian asked, will this be run against a string starting with `view.py` or against an entire url? For the former case, this simple regex should work fine in my opinion (using Python here):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = 'view.php?foo=bar&file=blablah123&anotherfoo=anotherbar'

In [3]: re.sub(r'view\.php\?.*\bfile=(\w+).*', '/file/\g<1>', s)
Out[3]: '/file/blablah123'
```

Comment: You should remove that `.*` after `(\w+)` - its redundant.

Comment: @Lindrian If I remove the `.*` at the end, then the resulting string would be `'/file/blablah123&anotherfoo=anotherbar'` which is wrong, apparently.

Comment: I upvoted your (working :-)) answer but @Vlad-L was earlier, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: @PeterStahl: thats most likely because you're not ouputting the correct data. the .* has nothing to do with the match result you want.